# Which JVM languages are stackless?

Tags: jvm, stackless

Which Turing-complete language implementations on the JVM do not use the JVM stack as a call stack?

(I ask because I want to implement coroutines between Scala and another language in the same thread.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Morpho
- SISC (Second Interpreter of Scheme Code)

**Implementations which once did not use the JVM stack, but in their latest versions, do:**

- LuaJ, prior to version 2
- JRuby (in its experimental YARV bytecode interpreter, since removed)